# How to include a PDF in LATEX?

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex

I am using overleaf to write a report and currently I would like to add a PDF file to my appendix. I would like it if there was a text saying: Figure 1: blablabla below the file and if I could label it as (because it is referenced in my report).

I have tried:

```
\includepdf[pages=-,scale=1,pagecommand={\captionof{blablabla}\label{pdf:myFile}},linktodoc=false]{myFile.pdf}
```

Any ideas on how I could do?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre]?

Comment: @KJ Nice to meet you here! How are you doing? The ducks spend their lockdown with https://github.com/samcarter/ducksoftheyear :)